# If a matrix is positive-definite, is every term in its determinant (as sum over permutations) nonnegative?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, positive-definite

This question is not homework. As part of a different problem, I had the idea of constructing a matrix where, when computing the determinant, every term in the sum is nonnegative. Specifically, if $A$ is $n$x$n$ and

$$\det(A) = \sum_{\text{permutations } \sigma}\text{sign}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n A_{i,\sigma(i)}  $$
then I am asking whether if $A$ is positive definite then 
$$
\text{sign}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n A_{i, \sigma(i)} \ge 0
$$
for all permutations $\sigma: \{1,\dots,n\} \to \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Have you tried some concrete cases? There are very simple $2 \times 2$ counterexamples.

Comment: To add to @HansLundmark, not only are concrete cases also helpful, but so are special cases. For example, the $n\times n$ zero matrix seems to technically fulfill your requirements despite being completely uninteresting.

Comment: Are you trying to construct a single matrix, like your introduction talks about, or find a simpler condition that would imply it, as you suggest in the rest of the post? If the former, then there are simple $2 \times 2$ examples, such as \begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}